# ExoPlayer ConcatenatingMediaSource ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, exoplayer

After I clean the playlist and add new tracks, if I try to play the last track, I get the following error :

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal runtime error.
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=50; index=50
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource$ConcatenatedTimeline.getTimelineByChildIndex(ConcatenatingMediaSource.java:777)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.AbstractConcatenatedTimeline.getNextWindowIndex(AbstractConcatenatedTimeline.java:66)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline.getNextPeriodIndex(Timeline.java:670)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline.isLastPeriod(Timeline.java:692)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.isLastInTimeline(MediaPeriodQueue.java:747)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.getMediaPeriodInfoForContent(MediaPeriodQueue.java:714)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.getMediaPeriodInfo(MediaPeriodQueue.java:672)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.getFirstMediaPeriodInfo(MediaPeriodQueue.java:500)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaPeriodQueue.getNextMediaPeriodInfo(MediaPeriodQueue.java:125)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.maybeUpdateLoadingPeriod(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1482)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePeriods(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1367)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:495)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:301)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Index my last track is 49, i call function `seekTo(49, 0)`, but if i don't clean playlist and don't add new tracks all ok.
Code some functions:

```
 override fun addMusicInPlaylist(listSong: List<Song>, removeOld: Boolean) {
        val dataSource = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name))).createDataSource()
        dataSource.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://example.com/")
        val factory = DataSource.Factory { dataSource }
        val listMediaSources = ArrayList<MediaSource>()
        listSong.forEachWithIndex { i, it->
            listMediaSources.add(SongMediaSource(ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(it.url)),it))
        }
        if (removeOld) {
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
            mediaSources.clear {
                mediaSources.addMediaSources(listMediaSources)
            }
        } else
            mediaSources.addMediaSources(listMediaSources)

    }

override fun changeSong(song: Song, position: Int) {
        if (songId == song.songId)
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = !exoPlayer.playWhenReady
        else {
            songId = song.songId
            exoPlayer.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET)
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should also clear your last played index as when your Playlist is cleared its not necessary that user will add more songs in their playlist than before. If your index is greater than current Playlist size and you try to access it it will obviously fail.

Comment: @nitinkumarp I'm only trying to access the last track, after cleaning and adding new tracks. If I play the penultimate track, everything is ok and it plays correctly, but when i turn on the last one, the library tries to find the next track and throws an exception. But If i add tracks without cleaning such a problem is not present

Comment: Add your code of `seekTo()`

Comment: `seekTo()` is the function of the exoplayer library